# Determining the intersection and sum of vector subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space  and let $V= \mathbb{R}^3, W_1 =\{(a,b,b)\mid a, b\in \mathbb{R}\}$, and $W_2= \{(c,-d,d)\mid c,d \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

> Find $W_1 \cap W_2$ and $W_1 + W_2$.

Comment: Are $c,d \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: yeah i forgot to indicate that c,d is an element of R too

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can prove that both $W_1, W_2$ are subspaces of $V$. Observe that $W_1+W_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R^3}$, you can show the other direction $\mathbb{R^3} \subseteq W_1+W_2$. This means for any $x \in \mathbb{R^3}$, say $x = (m,n,p)$, you show there exist $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ such that: $(m,n,p) = (a,b,b)+(c,-d,d) \iff a+c =m, b-d = n, b+d =p$, and this system does have a solution in $a,b,c,d$. Thus we've shown: $\mathbb{R^3} = W_1+W_2$, and for the first question, if $x \in W_1\cap W_2$, then $x \in W_1$, and $x \in W_2\Rightarrow (a,b,b) = (c,-d,d)$ for some reals $a,b,c,d$. This means $ b= -d = d \Rightarrow b = d = 0, a = c\Rightarrow x = (a,0,0) = a(1,0,0)$. Thus $W_1\cap W_2 = \{(a,0,0) \mid a \in \mathbb{R}\}$.